# All of a sudden Eclipse starts to complain "The method asList(int, int) is undefined for the type Arrays"

Tags: java, eclipse

It is a bit odd because all of a sudden I got this error.

"The method asList(int, int) is undefined for the type Arrays".

The odd thing is that there were a few programs that were working, which are not working now. Surely there should be some setting.

Comment: Share your code and restart your eclipse once just in case. ;-)

Comment: Did you switch to an earlier Java version (pre Java 5)?

Comment: Did you perhaps create a class called `Arrays` other than `java.util.Arrays` and import it into your sources?

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I actually had a class called Array and it messed it up.

Comment: You can avoid the confusion by typing for instance `java.util.Arrays.asList(7, 13)`. The package name prefix will allow you to use two classes with the same class name in the same Java source file.